# How to load and view contents of pdf file in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I'm trying to load a pdf document that contains text and images, then I want to view selected contents from this document ( will apply regex later). So far this is my progress, it is not much but I'm getting an error (Message: Can not open 'desktop\test.pdf' file for reading.), please help.

```
<?php   $filename = 'desktop\test.pdf';

$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($filename);      

?>
```

Comment: To debug this further, you can look for the Parser.php file in the Zend PDF package. That's where the exception giving this error is thrown (in constructor, line 365 for me). Then, remove the at-sign (`@`) from `@fopen($source, 'rb')`, try again, and you'll get some more helpful info in error log. For me, it was just that I put my PDF in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

just try with below one of them will sure work for you

Method 1: Get the binary string outside of Zend_Pdf

```
$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file.pdf')
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf($file);
```

Method 2: Set the $load parameter true

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf('path/to/file.pdf', null, true);
```

Method 3: Use the static load-method

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('path/to/file.pdf');
```

try to give correct path every time might be absulute path will work or relative may be.

Comment: I tried all these methods, nothing is working, getting the same error message again. Could it be my file path? I'm using windows.